# Null pointer exception when try to chnage orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

When change layout Null Pointer Exception. I used Fragment.

When I try to chnage orientation in layout. I used public class MainFragment extends SherlockFragment

Logcat below 
Error like :

```
05-12 14:38:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(6773): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 14:38:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(6773): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 14:38:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(6773):     at com.android.aa.adapter.VideoListAdapter.<init>(VideoListAdapter.java:47)
05-12 14:38:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(6773):     at com.android.aa.tv.MainFragment$AsyncAction.onPostExecute(MainFragment.java:134)
05-12 14:38:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(6773):     at com.android.aa.tv.MainFragment$AsyncAction.onPostExecute(MainFragment.java:1)
05-12 14:38:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(6773):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:590)
05-12 14:38:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(6773):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:149)
05-12 14:38:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(6773):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:603)
05-12 14:38:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(6773):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-12 14:38:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(6773):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
05-12 14:38:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(6773):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
05-12 14:38:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(6773):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 14:38:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(6773):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-12 14:38:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(6773):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-12 14:38:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(6773):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-12 14:38:27.676: E/AndroidRuntime(6773):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //setRetainInstance(true);

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container,false);
        initView();
        return rootView;
}

private void initView() { 

    new AsyncAction().execute(null, null, null);

}
```

**((ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoListView)).setAdapter(new VideoListAdapter(getActivity(),aryThumbnail,aryUrl,aryTitle,aryDesc));**

```
private class AsyncAction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{           
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) 
    {
         callRecentVideo();
         return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
         pd.dismiss();Log.e("length",String.valueOf(aryThumbnail.size()));
         ((ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoListView)).setAdapter(new VideoListAdapter(getActivity(),aryThumbnail,aryUrl,aryTitle,aryDesc));
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pd.setTitle("app");
        pd.setMessage("Please wait while we are loading..");
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is line 47 in `VideoListAdapter.java`?. When orientation changes activity is destroyed and recreated

Comment: mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Comment: Where does context come from in VideoListAdapter? You really need to post more code.

Comment: @Nick where do you have that post that part of the code

Comment: @JamieB Please check code

Comment: @Raghunandan: Please check code. please

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are recreating the fragment once again and executing the asyntask which will result nullpointer..

solution you need to keep the asyntask alive each time you change the orientation..

there is a good implementation [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html);

Comment: can you say me what I have to do in this ?

Comment: @Nick click on the link its a tuturial how to keep alive the asynctask

Comment: I seen that link and added both class. now how to use below code.

Comment: see above link please

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem using this, in my manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="<package-name>"
        android:label="<app-name>" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
    </activity>
```